# What are the differences between two generations of Canon EF-S 55-250mm f4-5.6 IS?

Tags: lens, canon, telephoto

I was going to buy Canon EF-S 55-250mm f4-5.6 IS lens from eBay. But I saw there is a another lens available as MK II with same focal lengths. I googled to find difference between above lenses, but there were no results for that.

Can anyone explain the difference between these two lenses? Something I noticed is that the MK II lens is priced a little bit higher than the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [announcement](http://www.dpreview.com/news/1106/11061304canon55_200_ISII.asp), the mkII version is only a few months old (the original one was [introduced](http://www.dpreview.com/news/0708/07082007canonefs18-55and55-250.asp) in 2007). Compared to older one, it seems to have gotten only a cosmetic makeover - some writings have moved to other locations and the plastic seems different. It has been [noted](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1054062) that some of the new design features, like painted mount marker instead of a moulded one, and one-color finish (which I consider nicer), are probably *cheaper* than the older design.

The UD glass and Canon Super Spectra coating touted in the announcement were actually already present in the original design.