# Difference between Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS and Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS II?

Tags: canon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between two generations of Canon EF-S 55-250mm f4-5.6 IS?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/what-are-the-differences-between-two-generations-of-canon-ef-s-55-250mm-f4-5-6-i)

What is th edifference between these 2 lens Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS and Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS II??

Comment: Cosmetic and IS

Comment: @Gapton what has changed in IS?

Comment: @Swetha - Welcome to photo stack exchange, it looks like this question has already been asked, so we will point you to the above answer by Imre that already has solutions. Thanks for the question and please ask more!

Answer (score 0):

The specifications are identical:

1. [Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/eos_slr_camera_systems/lenses/ef_s_55_250mm_f_4_5_6_is#Specifications)
2. [Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS II](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/ef_lens_lineup/ef_s_55_250mm_f_4_5_6_is_ii#Specifications)

While I haven't used or seen reviews of the new II version, the new version is unlikely to have significant changes to the optic quality. There's a discussion [here](http://www.canonrumors.com/forum/index.php?topic=1621.0) on this topic. Possible changes involve a minor adjustment to the IS algorithm to allow different behaviour when panning and/or minor lens coating changes.