# Why would the Canon EF-S 55-250 IS II be cheaper than the first version?

Tags: lens, canon, pricing

I was about to order the Canon EFS 55-250mm f/4.0-5.6 IS Telephoto Zoom Lens from Amazon, when I learned about the difference between a Grey Market / Imported versions. Not only that, I saw that there is a version II available, and the weird thing is that the first version is being sold for $240 in Amazon, while version II is being sold for $183.

I googled around to see if the second version had any compromises or got downgraded someway to make it cheaper, but it doesn't appear so. My question is..is there a reason why the first version would be better or more expensive?

Here are the links:

[Version I ($240)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0011NVMO8)
[Version II ($183)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0056E49MK)

Comment: The list price is the same for both the lenses ($299). Version I is sold by Amazon, but version II is sold by PHOTOTECH _through_ Amazon. Maybe PHOTOTECH can give higher discounts due to a favourable deal they have with Canon or some other reason. I don't think that the price difference has something to do with the capacities of these lenses but with the seller.

Comment: so version II would actually be logically better (improved somehow), right? Also if you want to post your reply as an Answer instead of a comment, I can accept it Bart. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Price Difference

The list price is the same for both the lenses ($299).

Version I is sold by Amazon, but version II is sold by PHOTOTECH through Amazon. Maybe PHOTOTECH can give higher discounts due to a favourable deal they have with Canon, a stock clearance sale or some other reason. The price difference has nothing to do with the capacities of these lenses but with the seller.

### Physical Difference

For the physical differences between the two lenses, see [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/what-are-the-differences-between-two-generations-of-canon-ef-s-55-250mm-f4-5-6-i) question.

Comment: The one thing to make sure (and it may be a cause for the price reduction) is whether the seller is an official Canon seller (Amazon are for sure).

Comment: huge +1 to ysap, it has an impact on your ability to register the lens for service later.